# Html Form - Is there a way to choose between &#xHHHH; and &#DDDD; format?

Tags: php, html, encoding

Subject says it all.  I have an html form in a php script where data is entered, I noticed unicode chars get converted to the &#DDDD; format.  But to save space, I'd like to have it encoded in the database as the Hex format.  Is there a way to make that happen automatically?

UTF-8 can't be used due to backwards compatibility with existing characters and their values.

TIA!!

Comment: Since it's even up to 65536 (&#xFFFF; vs &#65535;) and only +1 for the next batch, maybe just leave it $#DDDD; format.  But would still like to know if there is a way to tell the form or html which to use.

Comment: Why do you want to save html entities in a database?